# MSBuild.exe doesn't use publish profile (pubxml)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a website and a publish profile on TFS. One all files are on build server, I execute the command below:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=my_publish_profile.pubxml /fl /flp:logfile=BuildOutput.log;verbosity=detailed "%WORKSPACE%\my_project.csproj"`

But msbuild.exe doesn't use the configuration I specified in that file. I wonder if I need to pass additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the full path to the pubxml file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "D:\Jenkins\1.03 MckinseyBranch1 Minimal Deployment_Webdeploy\workspace\Mckinsey.sln" /tv:4.0 /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=test.pubxml;**VisualStudioVersion=12.0**

I noticed the settings in "PublishProfile" file are honored only when **VisualStudioVersion=12.0** is used. It does not work for other values of **VisualStudioVersion=12.0**. If VisualStudioVersion=10.0 is used, files are published at '(WebSite root)\obj\Release\Package'

To use **VisualStudioVersion=12.0**, you should have file "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" at path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications"